# Asp.Net WebApi Core 2.0 Identity With JWTBearer Without cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building Web service using ASP.Net Core WebApi. I would like to use Identity and also JWTBearer authentication. My code in ConfigureService method of Startup class id:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  //JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuer").Value;
    options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuer").Value;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
      ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]))
    };
  });
```

Configure method of Startup class contains:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

My problem is that when I call `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` it include cookie with authentication token to response. But i Would like only to use JwtBearer in header. Is there any option how to disable cookies for `SignInManager`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync()`: it does exactly the same checks but unlike `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`, doesn't return any cookie.